# correcting particleSystem speed?

Tags: unity, particles

When I kill my enemy some kind of gold get out of him. This gold moves forward to the player if he gets close. In my cast it moves very slow. I need it becomes more faster when get close to the player.
[Example](https://giphy.com/gifs/13uJY8To7xATLO)

```
using System.Collections;
public class souls : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform _attractorTransform;

private float paticlesFarFrom;

private ParticleSystem _particleSystem;

private ParticleSystem.Particle[] _particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[1000];
void Start ()

{

_particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ();

}
public void Update()

{

if (GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().isPlaying) {

int length = _particleSystem.GetParticles (_particles);

Vector3 attractorPosition = _attractorTransform.position;

for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {

paticlesFarFrom = Vector3.Distance(_particles[i].position,_attractorTransform.transform.position);

if (paticlesFarFrom <=200) {
 // this line need to fix
_particles [i].position = _particles [i].position + (attractorPosition - _particles [i].position) / (_particles [i].remainingLifetime) * Time.deltaTime;
}

}

_particleSystem.SetParticles (_particles, length);

}
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your code (I don't really understand it) but since there's speed involved, you can just make the object's speed fast (like 100 times what it is right now) and then constantly update it with a (speed/distancefromplayer).

Comment: I tried that. the result not as the example "fable 2". what's wrong with my script ?

Comment: Try putting this part in parantheses like so: ((attractorPosition - _particles [i].position) / (_particles [i].remainingLifetime)) I'm not sure if it'll help but it might (like I said, I'm not sure what the code is doing there, have you checked whether it goes inside the if clause at all?)

Comment: No problem. Write down the exact solution if you ever find it (or if you're satisfied with the solution you just found, write that) as an answer and choose it, so other can benefit :)